# both firebase and flutter local notifications handle background notificaiton

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm facing an issue with displaying double notifications when the app in the background firebase handle the notification first and then the flutter local notification display a popup on the screen anyway to make firebase not show the notification

p.s remove the
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

make the app not handle notifications on background

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (RemoteMessage? message) async {
      
        _showNotification(
            id: 0,
            title: message?.notification?.title ?? '',
            body: message?.notification?.body ?? '');
      },
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage? message) async {

  _showNotification(
      id: 0,
      title: message?.notification?.title ?? '',
      body: message?.notification?.body ?? '');

}
```

the firebase package contains title and body in the notification flag even if the app working in the background
any way to make the notification only handled by flutter_local_notification package

Answer (score 1):

- One possible problem is the initialization of your local_notification_package

##### It should be a topmost initialization, i.e you initialize the `flutter_local_notifications` package and the android channel before calling `_showNotification` function

- Another possible problem is the initialization of firebase. It should be done before the app runs, since it is a foreground notification

Comment: already did that

Answer (score 1):

#### Your firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler will look like.......

```html
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage? message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); //initialize firebase
  //INITIALIZE YOUR FLUTTER LOCAL NOTIFICATION PACKAGE 
  // INITIALIZE YOUR ANDROID CHANNEL
  //then show the notification
  _showNotification(
      id: 0,
      title: message?.notification?.title ?? '',
      body: message?.notification?.body ?? '');

}
```

Comment: the same it still displays two notifications. any way to stop flutter local notification to display the notification in the device notification center?? it will be a workaround for this issue

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem until added

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
android:value="high_importance_channel" />
```

in the android manifest file.

Also, keep in mind the value `high_importance_channel` could be any thing you want but it should be the same as the one you declare in your flutter code like below:

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel', //channel id
  'High Importance Notifications', //title
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', //description
  importance: Importance.max,
);
```

You can find more info [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/)

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was passing an empty map to the notification field in message sent by firebase, because both title and body are null it does not trigger the SDK to show a notification :

```
`notification : {},`
```

then showing my notification via the message data passed to flutter local notifications package

as shown

`{ "message":{ "token":"token_1", "data":{"title":"FCM Message", "body":"This is an FCM notification message!" }, "notification":{} } }`

Omitting notification totally causes iOS to not display push notifications when app is terminated and including it with "body" and "title" fields causes push notifications to display twice each by the SDK and flutter local notifications, Hope this helps. Cheers